# How to call ListView adapter's getItem(i) from Activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView adapter:

```
public class CartList extends BaseAdapter {
    // ...
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) { return i; }
    // ...

}
```

And I have this activity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv_list;
    static ArrayList<CartEntity> lista1 = new ArrayList<CartEntity>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // my_code;
        lv_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final int pos = position;
                CartEntity item = CartList.getItem(pos);
            }
        });
    }
```

That shows this error:

> Non-static method 'getItem(int)' cannot be referenced from a static
>   context

How Can i call the method to get selected item?
Without 'getItem' line works fine, but i need the object.

Comment: Where you are populating your `ListView` and where you have created object of your adapter which is responsible for populating your list?

Comment: learn about access modifier in java.

Comment: in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` with `CartList adapter = new CartList(this, lista1); lv_list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn about access modifier in java. You can get the item from `lista1` call get() method from `ArrayList` like this `CartEntity item = lista1.get(pos)`

or if you still want `CartEntity` from the adapter make the adapter as local variable or instance variable and you can call `getItem()` because it's public

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv_list;
static ArrayList<CartEntity> lista1 = new ArrayList<CartEntity>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create object from Adapter Class
    CartList cartAdapter = new CartList();

    // my_code;
    lv_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final int pos = position;
            CartEntity item = cartAdapter.getItem(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not created a CartList, you are trying to use the method without an actual CartList object created, so the list will be empty.  You need to instantiate it and assign a CartList object to a variable somewhere in your class.

For Example:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CartList mCartList = new CartList();
```

The problem is, mCartList may still be empty.  You need to be sure it has data.  I would also learn what access modifiers in Java and Object Oriented Programming do, such as Public, Private, Protected, Static, etc.